# test a stored procedure in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, testing, stored-procedures, insert, mysql-workbench

I have an Insert stored procedure where I am inserting into 2 tables. The second table using the Last_Insert_ID of the first table. Here is my sproc:

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_user_create`(

    IN oFarmName      varchar(45),
    IN oFirstName        varchar(45),
    IN oAddress1         varchar(45),
    IN oCity         varchar(45),
    IN oState         varchar(45),
    IN oZip         varchar(45),
    IN oCountry         varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
    insert into intelliair.individual
    ( FarmName, FirstName)
    values ( oFarmName, oFirstName);
       insert into intelliair.address
    (IndividualID, Address1, City, State, Zip, Country)
    Values (Last_Insert_ID(), oAddress1, oCity, oState, oZip, oCountry);
END
```

Here is how I am testing the query in MySql workbench:

```
call new_user_create(@myFarm, @MyName, @MyAddress, @MyCity, @MyState, @MyZip, @MyCountry)
```

There error I get is: "Column Address1 cannot be null"

Where am I going wronng? Is it in the sproc? Or the way I am calling it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"*Column Address1 cannot be null*"  indicates that the `intelliair.address.Address1` field must be defined `not null`.

And, I don't think that you pre defined value for `@MyAddress` before passing it to the stored procedure.
Unless defined it is treated as `NULL` and hence is the error thrown.

To cross check values before calling the stored procedure like :

```
select @MyAddress;  -- ,@myFarm, @MyName, @MyCity, @MyState, @MyZip, @MyCountry;
```

**Update 1**:

You can call stored procedure by directly inputting values for each of the parameters.
**Example**:

```
call new_user_create(  
    'my Farm value', -- @myFarm  
    'E B', -- @MyName  
    'My Address is SO', -- @MyAddress1  
    'My City is Coders', -- @MyCity  
    'CA', -- @MyState  
    '12345', -- @MyZip  
    'US' -- @MyCountry
);
```

Comment: thank you. this is where i am confused. I am not exactly sure hot to test (call) the sproc. The values I want inserted into the table is : MyAdress. But I thought the syntax was : @Myaddress. How would I properly call this sproc using actual values?

Comment: Also, when i remove the @ symbol and just use MyName as the actual value. It tells me that Myname column doesn't exist.

Comment: You can just input the actual values while calling, unless interested in variables. Like `call my_sp( 'value1', 'value2', .. )`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown by an INSERT (or UPDATE) statement, that is assigning a NULL value to a column named `Address1` that is declared to be `NOT NULL`.

The most likely explanation, from what you show, is that the value passed in as the oAddress1 parameter is NULL, and the exception is being thrown by the second INSERT statement.

The most likely explanation, therefore, is that when the call to the procedure is made, the `@MyAddress` user variable is not assigned a value.

(You can verify there is not an `Address1` column on the intelliair.individual table, or that if there is one, it's not defined as `NOT NULL`.)

(There's also a possibility that it's not one of your statements that's throwing the exception, but rather a recursive SQL statement, like an INSERT statement in a BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW trigger.)

Answer (score 0):

```
USE lportal;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `iemp`(IN eid INT(11),IN ename varchar(15),IN dname varchar(15),IN doj DATE)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO e_emp (eid,ename,dname,doj) VALUES (eid,ename,dname,doj);
END
```